# Power chord rating

Tags: power-supply, voltage, mains

Im using a power chord of rating 240V, 10A. When Im using the input voltage of 115Vac, that time also the maximum available current is 10A or different?

Comment: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/6f/b1/dc/6fb1dc447c7431464e8075bab8b8a9ac.jpg

Comment: The only power chords I know of are the ones I play on my guitar...

Comment: @Majenko E5 G5 A5 C5?

Comment: OP, a [power chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_chord) is a combination of notes played on a guitar and characteristic of heavy metal and other kinds of rock music. You probably want to ask about power *cords*. Note: You can edit your question at any time.

Answer (score 5):

The current (amps) rating of the cord is based on the metal cross-dimension (and metal resistance): as current increases, heating also increases.

The voltage rating is based on how much voltage can be on the wire before the insulation (coating) on the wire breaks down.

Because these are separate factors, reducing the voltage does not affect the maximum current (significantly) so your 240V 10A wire is still rated at 10A with lower voltage.